# How can I adjust the space-between not splitting its last two items in a 3-col situation?

Tags: html, css

The last row, there are only two blocks and they got split on the left and right.

Is it possible to let they just aligned normally?

[image]

```css
#wrap {
  width: 500px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  width: 32%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top:9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `justify-content: space-between;` but add the margin yourself:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  width: 32%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.item+.item {
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```